# Basic C++ Application has extra output then it should

Tags: c++

So I'm writing a basic application and for some reason when I run the program a bunch of numbers pop up before my intended output. It was working fine until I added the "std::cout" lines to have the outputs only be 2 decimals. The general gist of the application is a program acts as a self-checkout register at a store and lets the user buy 2 items. And yes I know the code probably looks really bad, I'm still super new to C++.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
int main()
{

float price1;
float number1;
float price2;
float number2;
float priceofitemplustax1;
float priceofitemplustax2;
float total;

std::cout << std::fixed;
std::cout << std::setprecision(2);
std::cout << price1;
std::cout << price2;
std::cout << priceofitemplustax1;
std::cout << priceofitemplustax2;
std::cout << total;

cout << endl << "Please scan your first item." <<endl;

cin.get();

cout << endl << "How many of that item are you buying? "<<endl;

cin >> number1;

cout << endl << "How much is that item?"<<endl;

cin >> price1;

priceofitemplustax1 = (number1 * price1) * 1.0875;

cout << endl << "So you want " << number1 << " of this item? Adding tax that will be " << priceofitemplustax1 << "."<<endl;

cin.get();

cout << endl << "Please scan your second item."<<endl;

cin.get();

cout << endl << "How many of that item are you buying? "<<endl;

cin >> number2;

cout << endl << "How much is that item?"<<endl;

cin >> price2;

priceofitemplustax2 = (number2 * price2) * 1.0875;

cout << endl << "So you want " << number2 << " of this item? Adding tax that will be " << priceofitemplustax2 << "."<<endl;

cin.get();

total = priceofitemplustax1 + priceofitemplustax2;

cout << endl << "So your final total for this shopping trip including tax is " << total << "."<<endl;

cin.get();

cout << endl << "Your reciept will print below."<<endl;

cin.get();

cout << setw(14) << right << "Number of Item" << setw(10) << right << "Price" << setw(20) << "Price plus tax" << endl;

cout << setw(14) << right << number1 << setw(10) << right << price1 << setw(20) << priceofitemplustax1 << endl;

cout << setw(14) << right << number2 << setw(10) << right << price2 << setw(20) << priceofitemplustax2 << endl;

cout << endl;

cout << endl;

cout << setw(8) << right << "Total is" << setw(10) << total << price2 << endl;

cin.get();
}
```

Comment: `std::cout << std::setprecision(2);
std::cout << price1;
std::cout << price2;
std::cout << priceofitemplustax1;
std::cout << priceofitemplustax2;
std::cout << total;` here you write 5 floats.

Comment: Is that bad? I'm still not sure how to fix that.

Comment: Weren’t that you who saw more output than he wanted? Don’t output if you don’t want it.

Comment: Editorial aside : Never use floating point numbers to represent currency values.

Comment: Oh I'm dumb, I got it, I didn't realize those were output lines, I should have realized that by the "cout" part of it. Thank you, also how do I mark your comment as the correct answer.

Comment: I made it an answer.

Comment: Why did you think you had to `cout` them and what that would do? Also, even if it's moot in this context, for emphasis: by doing that, you were reading uninitialised variables, which is UB. Don't do that.

Answer (score 1):

```
std::cout << std::setprecision(2); 
std::cout << price1;
std::cout << price2;
std::cout << priceofitemplustax1; 
std::cout << priceofitemplustax2; std::cout << total;
```

here you write 5 floats

Answer (score 0):

The lines

```
std::cout << std::fixed;   // sets a format
std::cout << std::setprecision(2);  // sets a format
```

set the streams output format.

The lines

```
std::cout << price1;  // outputs a number
std::cout << price2;  // outputs a number
std::cout << priceofitemplustax1;  // outputs a number
std::cout << priceofitemplustax2;  // outputs a number
std::cout << total;  // outputs a number
```

print the variables to the stream.

Just remove the variable output lines. Do not accept this answer - Credit goes to manni66